# Body text is hidden when div is sticky at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm tried to fix sticky on bottom of the page using javascript/jquery but the sticky is hidden the body text. I need to show all body text without hidden along with sticky, I'm not able to figure out the issue, pls anyone suggest me what is the issue in my code.

[**CodePen Link**](https://codepen.io/burner/pen/pLyOjX)

**JS**

```
var link = $('#navbar');
var offset = link.offset();
var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;
var bottom = $(window).height() - top - link.height();
bottom = offset.top - bottom;
var right = $(window).width() - link.width();
right = offset.left - right;
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to give the `margin-bottom` to the `.content` equal to the `#navbar` height...So just calculate the `#navbar` height using `outerHeight()` jQuery and apply this value to `.content` using `css()` jQuery

```js
var link = $('#navbar');
var content = $('.content');
var linkHeight = link.outerHeight();
content.css({
  "margin-bottom": linkHeight
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestia e voluptatibus. illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus </p>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestia e voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

---

Or another solution is use `position:sticky` if **[[browser support]](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)** is not an issue

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestia e voluptatibus. illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus </p>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestia e voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you just use the `margin-bottom` attribute of css

```
<div class="content" style="margin-bottom: 100px">
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct solution because of if sticky bar height is 100px, the solution is fine but In future sticky bar height might increase 100px to 120px such case it wont help again i have to change margin-bottom values

Answer (score 0):

You can give a padding:bottom; value for the content div.

```
.content {
    padding-bottom: 88px;   
}
```

But if you do like that maybe you have to write some media query because the text will wrap and the height will change. in that case you can use this method.

```
$(".content").css("padding-bottom",$("#navbar").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use margin-bottom to achieve what you want.

`$(".content").css("margin-bottom",$("#navbar").height());`

You can use this code block to set margin-bottom for your content based on the static bar height dynamically.

Hope this helps